# how to return a double rounded to tenths

Tags: java, rounding

I am trying to return a double so that it rounds up to the tenths. I have:

```
 roundedTemp = (double)Math.round(tempNum *10)/10;
 return roundedTemp;
```

What am I doing wrong? I get it back to 2 decimal places...

Comment: A `double` is a _base 2_ IEEE 754 floating point number; meaning it can have, and often has, trouble being rounded to an exact decimal ("deci" as in "ten") number.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get it back to 2 decimal places"... what are you doing that makes it appear that you're getting 2 decimal places?  Also, what is `tempNum`?  (That is, what is its value?  It would help to know if it's a very large or very small number.)

Comment: I want a value such that it returns #.#

Comment: Please be clearer.  You get `#.##` from _what_?  `System.out.println`?  `String.format`?  We are not mind readers.

Comment: Do you mean that `System.out.println(roundedTemp)` prints two digits after the decimal point?  Could you give at least one or two examples of values of `tempNum` for which that happens?

Answer (score 0):

Use DecimalFormat.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
```

Comment: That may be the correct answer if he just wants to *output* one decimal place.  But it looks like he wants (or might want) an actual rounded value, which is a different question.